# What should be the approach for language translation of app having multiple modules?

Tags: angular, translate, angular-translate, ngx-translate

I am confused guys that which approach should I follow for the language translation. I am currently using ngx-translate module.
The main problem is should I manage separate lang files for each module :-

[Current implementation, Using separate module lang files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRFj1.png)

Or should I keep one language file for all the modules? Please suggest the better approach.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Translate.stream can also be useful for wide apps and it will change the value according to the language changes.

```
constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
 this.translate
  .stream('my.i18n.key')
  .subscribe((res: string) => {
    console.log(res);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question might have different solutions based on how your application is consuming static data. I have recently implemented the language translation in our project.

I have gone through many blogs and vlogs that could help to organize this functionality in the app. When you should use modular approach in language JSON and when not.

Generally, modular approach for language comes in this picture when your application is consuming a lot of static data and every module has its own. Also, when you are following lazy loaded approach. This will help you to load the application in quite less time frame. So, you should follow this approach when your app has lazy loading and JSON becomes really big, it will help you to maintain module related  static data in one file.

Second approach can be followed, when your application shares lot of data between any modules, so instead of replicating same data in every module you can have one single file and share b/w them provided that JSON file remains small.

You can also follow the hybrid approach that means mixture of above two based on how your app is consuming data. I have used hybrid approach as some modules needed to share same static data from other modules and some modules only needs their own data.

Comment: Thank you Apoorva for the valuable suggestion!